# Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, android-studio-2.2

Installed Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 and getting this error:

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher

Screenshot:
[image]

I re-installed the JDK, still same issue.

I even tried to use the embedded JDK but still having the same issue:

[image]

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I had the same issue, but I have resolved it the next:

1) Install jdk1.8...

2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the **JDK** is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.

3) Click Ok.

Comment: Because it is not compatible with JRE 1.8

Comment: I upgraded Android Studio, but forgot to change the JDK location from 1.7 to 1.8 in the above setting.

Comment: @midhunhk you mean to change the directory to your main jdk location that will be found in prehaps "Programs\Java" as opposed to "Programs\Android"

Comment: Correcting Answer : 2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location,

Comment: but it didn't accept The jdk with Alret **Please choose a valid JDK directory.**

Comment: where can I find jdk 1.8? any links?

Comment: in the SDK location? choose the JDK directory? but it says sdk does not contain any platforms

Comment: I had the same issue and doing the same thing solve my problem as well. (I have 32 bit os/system)

Answer (score 57):

**REASON**

This happens because for now *they only ship 64bit JRE with Android Studio for Windows* which produces glitches in 32 bit systems.

**SOLUTION**

- do not use the embedded JDK: Go to File -> Project Structure dialog, uncheck "Use embedded JDK" and select the 32-bit JRE you've installed separately in your system
- decrease the memory footprint for Gradle in **gradle.properties**(Project Properties), for eg set it to **-Xmx768m**.

For more details: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219524

Comment: @Barun how did you do it? I'm a total beginner

Comment: @mc8 follow the instruction

Comment: Sorry but if choose **jre** directory say, *Please choose a valid JDK directory*, but if choose **jdk** don't show that error message

Comment: Notice that if your SDK path contains a space it warns and stupidly does not set the JDK path too. This is while it just warns that if SDK path conatins space the NDK may have problem. I moved my SDK from "Program Files" to a path without space and after that the SDK and JDK path was accepted by the project structure dialog.

Answer (score 3):

i think android studio has a 64bit kernel version which is giving the problem.
https://github.com/swcarpentry/windows-installer/issues/49

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry... Its much easy to solve your problem. Just SET you SDK-LOCATION and JDK-LOCATION.

- Click on Configure ( As Soon Android studio open )
- Click Project Default
- Click Project Structure
- Clik Android Sdk Location
- Select & Browse your Android SDK Location (Like: C:\Android\sdk)
- Uncheck ***USE EMBEDDED JDK LOCATION***
- Set & Browse JDK Location, Like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121