# Gradle compatibility error when launching sample Android NDK 'Hello JNI' app

Tags: java, android, c++, gradle, android-ndk

I am trying to compile the sample 'Hello JNI' program included in the Android NDK that is used to test basic Android NDK functionality. However, whenever I try to perform a Gradle sync using Android Studio I get the following error:

```
Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher
```

To be clear, I am using Windows 7 32-bit. I thought there might be a version mismatch so I reinstalled a 32-bit version of JDK and JRE and made sure that I was running the 32-bit version of Android Studio, but I keep getting the same error.

Thank you for any help you guys can give me.

Note: This has been identified as a duplicate question. While this is true, I have tried the answer given on the other question and it did not fix my problem. I would appreciate another answer if anyone knows an additional solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply switching to a 64-bit OS and I no longer get the error.