# Android studio 2.2 showing Error:CreateProcess error=216

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-2012, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed my Android Studio 2.2, but I keep getting an error message saying

"Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher"

I have tried all I could but its still not working. Check the attached image to see a screenshot of my android studio  [android studio showing Error:CreateProcess error=216](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Jqr.png)

Comment: Could it be that the version of Windows you are running isn't compatible.........?

Comment: Have you tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c

Comment: I have tried several times it didn't work for me. I have used over 3hours trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 3):

[Try this solution by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c) @user6442395

> 1) Install jdk1.8...
>
> 2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JKD is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.
>
> 3) Click Ok.

Comment: I have tried this many times but it keep reverting it back to the embedded JDK Folder I don't know what to do again but I will definitely try again. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: I think it worked but I have another problem saying "unable to start daemon process" what can I do?

Comment: Try deleting your .gradle from C:\Users\<username> directory

Comment: Do I need to delete it when my android studio is opened or i should close my android studio. I have deleted it once but i still see again.

Comment: Delete it when Studio is closed. After open studio. It should regenerate that file again. But also it should work normally

Comment: I have deleted the .gradle folder but when I run Android Studio again this the messgae i recieved " Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
"

Comment: 1) Click on file and select a other setting from dropdown menu and then select default setting.

2) Select build,Execution,Deployment option.

3) Select Compiler

4) Here add a following line in Additional build process VM option -Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=524m as show here http://i.stack.imgur.com/iPVIZ.png

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the jdk location in project structure

Follow those steps

Go to file -> project structure -> sdk location

Unselect Use embedded jdk(recommended)

Then Change the jdk location to C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_101

Then click OK and wait for the build to finish