# Android Studio 2.2 Gradle Project Failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2

Please resolve my issue during android programming, I am getting error as Gradle Project fail please refer screenshot and provide me the solutions.

Regards
Hussain[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI377.png)

Comment: Refer this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try install jdk1.8.

2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your directory where the JKD is located, by default Studio uses embedded JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.

3) Click Ok.