# Error:CreateProcess error=216 - Android Studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, windows

I recently Installed the Latest version of android studio i.e `Android 2.2.2` after all successful installation I tried opening the Application when opened it asked for the latest Java Version, then i installed the `Java JDK 1.8` and reopened the Application then it shows the following error : -

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64
>   (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

I tried changing the `JDK` location in the Project structure but it's not at all changing. I tried many times, even tried changing in the Gradle properties etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Comment: you JDK architecture has to match Android Studio architecture. Also if your sustem is x86, then you can use only x86 architecture