# Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with

Tags: android, java-8

please i have android studio 2.3.3 and jdk1.8 installed in my 32bit 4gbram system,and not to use the embedded jdk from the answers that seems to be working for all,but this problem still kills my time #help #help #help

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c

Comment: i saw that question and answer but if it worked for me,i woundn't be pleading for help,i have jdk1.8 in programfiles/java/jdk1.8 but if i uncheck the embedded jdk in android studio and choose this very one,nothing happens...and if i go back to project structure the embedded one is still checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded jdk9 and copied the whole directory from java to android and it worked..thanks