# Android studio doesn't load properly

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I just updated my windows 10 to the last version but when I open the Android studio I get this error :

```
Error: CreateProcess error = 216, This version of% 1 is not compatible with the
Version of Windows currently running. Check in the system information of your computer, and then contact the software publisher
```

I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: what is the version of android studio that you are using ?

Comment: The last one : Android Studio 2.3.3

Comment: Suggestion to that  

 - Install Jdk Version

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712337/7746134

Comment: I tried before but I get this error : Error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)