# Gradle project sync failed on Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am installing Android Studio 3.0.1 for the first time on my laptop, and I couldn't create my first Hello World app.

I get the following error:

```
Create process failed, error=216
Error:
Consult your IDE log for more details
```

The error can be seen on [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zp8J.png).

Comment: Probably your problem is related to Java JDK. Please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Comment: @jojSB yes u right .... thanks

Comment: @Al0x not the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> Project Structure,uncheck "Use embedded JDK" and select the 32-bit JDK.

Comment: select the 32-bit JRE or JDK ??

Comment: @YoussefElGarny 32-bit JRE

Comment: Thanks that was helpful .....but should select the JDK on the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I have resolved it the next:

> 1) Install jdk1.8...
>
> 2) In AndroidStudio File->Project Structure->SDK Location, select your
>   directory where the JDK is located, by default Studio uses embedded
>   JDK but for some reason it produces error=216.
>
> 3) Click Ok.

Answer (score 1):

### 1st Solution : -

- Goto File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

### 2nd Solution : -

1. Shutdown Android Studio
2. Rename .gradle folder in the user home directory
3. Restart Android Studio 
   4.Rebuild/Clean project.
4. Done

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, using the solution Android Studio provides, just click on the link in the bottom left corner:

1. Click the error message at top "Gradle project sync failed" where the text says ´Open message view´
2. In the "Message Gradle Sync" window on the bottom left corner, click the provided solution "Install missing ... "
3. Repeat 1 and 2 if necessary

[image: Android Studio providing a solution]

Answer (score 0):

First on the yellow error banner *click open 'messages' view* see pic1 then in the new view that opened up click *install ___________* **see pic2 & pic3** then click try again if you get the same error in the messages view then you will have to install it manually-
If one or both of these do not install, put the *downloading ______________* **(see pic4)** into chrome and it will download it, now extract the file and put it in the right place.

The build tools place is

```
C:\Users\<name of active user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2
```

The ndk package place is:

```
C:\Users\<name of active user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
```

Delete all the files in the folder and paste the new files from the folder you just downloaded and extracted. The files you download and the ones you paste in should look similar but not exactly the same. Once you do this the problem should be solved and you can press "try again"

**pic1**
[image: pic1]
**pic2**
[image: pic2]
**pic3**
[image: pic3]
**pic4**
[image: pic4]