# find Build Tools revision 27.0.3

Tags: android-studio

[Gradle project sync failed on Android Studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513196/gradle-project-sync-failed-on-android-studio-3-0-1/51046826#51046826)

I do what it was said here and I got this error:

[image]

How shall I proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install build-tools package. For installing it manually, follow these steps:

1. Download the "build-tools_r27.0.3-windows" directly from the following link:
   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r27.0.3-windows.zip
2. On your "SDK" directory, create a new folder and rename it to "build-tools".
3. Extract the downloaded file in the "build-tools" folder.
4. Finally, Restart Android studio.