# Android studio installation gradle error

Tags: android

I have tried installing, my android studio more than once but it keeps telling me

1. Preview is unavailable until a successful build
2. gradle sync failed this version is not compatible.

   But I downloaded the android studio for a 32-bit operating system.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37624369/9119277)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712337/1576416