# Error 216 in my windows 10

Tags: android

Hey I have installed android studio in my Win10 but it is not working properly as when it is building it is saying -

***Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher***
Also i have tried this solution -
File -> Project Structure -> Unchecked Used Embedded JDK -> Set My JDK Path

but it keep reverting it back to the embedded JDK Folder I don't know what to do again but I will definitely try again. I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c)

Comment: Hey bro i have used this solution but it is reverting it back to the embedded JDK folder....