# error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

Tags: java, android

I'm having issues with running my first project in Android Studio.

My system information is:
[image: 64-bit operating system]

I installed Android Studio 3.3 for Windows 64-bit from here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAj4biBRC-ARIsAA4WaFghk17DIUiHKwmX4-yiQfRpBRkxKqR8beYvgZE2mN5hmgAi2uWtFYQaAgpSEALw_wcB

However, when I create a new empty project and try to run it I get the following error:
error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running

I tried using the embedded jdk and also changing it here (using jdk I installed previously for other purposes):
[image: Using existing jdk]

I also get the following error:
Emulator: Warning: restoring GLES1 context from snapshot. App may need reloading.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried : https://stackoverflow.com/q/37624369/1318946

Comment: If you mean changing the jdk in Project structure I did, it didn't help. It seems to me that other users with this error are running a 32bit Windows, while mine is 64bit.