# Error:CreateProcess error=216 - Clion 2020.1.2

Tags: c++, windows, clion

I just Installed the Latest version of Clion 2020.1.2*64 and. when I run the code, the following problem occurs.
CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

need help!

Comment: God DAMN those one percenters! They're even ruining compilers now! But seriously, that "%1" is probably a scripting command that didn't get filled out correctly. What happens if you use CLion's runner to execute a known good executable?

Comment: Do you have 32bit Windows installation?

Comment: Please, follow the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37624369/android-studio-error-errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1-is-not-c